# How to get current XHR object?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

My requirement is to add cancel button to AJAX file upload. I know how to add Cancel button when upload starts but how can I get current XHR object to call abort() method on it?

Current code:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.rpke_cancel_btn = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            var el = Drupal.ajax['edit-xml-file-upload-button'];
            el.options.beforeSubmit = function (form_values, element, options) {
                $(el.element).parent().append($('<input>').attr({
                    'type' : 'button',
                    'value': Drupal.t('Cancel')
                }).click(function() {
                        //need the way to obtain XHR object here
                    }))
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I tried:

```
 Drupal.ajax['edit-xml-file-upload-button'].ajaxing = false;
```

but it does not work :(

**[EDIT]**

Now I think this is not possible because Drupal does not store XHR object returned by $.ajax()